# How can I get my data in alphabetic order with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on the code of someone else and try to get the data of a country list (generated by clicking on a map) in alphabetic order.

It should be like this:

- Company 1 / City A
- Company 2 / City B
- Company 3 / City C
- Company A / City D   (if in the same city then in alphabetic order of the company names)
- Company B / City D
- Company C / City D
- Company 7 / City E

This is my code:

```
break;
    default:                            // THIS IS THE TITLE LIKE NOTRH AMERICA
      $ret .= '
            <div class="casino_country_box">
                <a class="all_contry_link" href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/' . $continent . '/all/1">' . l::open_all() . '</a>
                <div class="casino_country_box_title">  
                    <p>' . $cont_db['name_' . $lang] . '</p>
                </div>
                <div class="casino_cuntry_link ';   // THIS IS FOR THE COUNTRY TOP BOX
      if ($this->data->getGet('all', 'int'))
        $ret .= 'show_all';             // IF "SHOW ALL" THEN SHOW COMPANIES IN THE ALL COUNTIES
      $ret .= '">
            ';
      foreach ($contry as $g => $v) {   // FOR EACH COUNTRY 
        if ($_GET['country'] && $_GET['country'] == $v['id'])
          $ret .= '<a style="color:orange; text-decoration: underline !important;" href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/' . $continent . '/' . $v['id'] . '">' . $v['name_' . $lang] . '</a>';
        else {
          if ($v['active'] == 1)        // IF THE COUNTRY IS ACTIVE = LINK IS ACTIVE
            $ret .= '<a href="' . $lang . '/casino/continent/' . $continent . '/' . $v['id'] . '">' . $v['name_' . $lang] . '</a>';
          else                          // IF THE COUNTRY IS NOT ACTIVE = NO ACTIVE LINK
            $ret .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="no_active">' . $v['name_' . $lang] . '</a>';
        }
      }
      $ret .= '</div></div>';
break;
```

Comment: sort order at db query before loop `ORDER BY country asc, company asc`  - [mysql order-by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your city/company array in your example code, but with an array of city/company like -

```
$array = array(
               array('company'=> 'Google', 'city'=> 'Dallas'),
               array('company'=> 'Sony', 'city'=> 'Albuquerque'),
               array('company'=> 'IBM', 'city'=> 'Dallas'),
               array('company'=> 'GE', 'city'=> 'Boston'),
               array('company'=> 'Apple', 'city'=> 'Dallas'),
               array('company'=> 'Dell', 'city'=> 'El Paso'),
               array('company'=> 'Skype', 'city'=> 'Chicago')
          );
```

---

you can use [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $city[$key]  = $row['city'];
    $company[$key] = $row['company'];
}

array_multisort($city, SORT_ASC, $company, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

---

or using [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function mySort($a,$b) {
    if ($a['city'] == $b['city']) {
        return strcmp($a["company"], $b["company"]);
    } else {
        return strcmp($a["city"], $b["city"]);
    }
}
usort($array, 'mySort');
```

---

example phpFiddle at http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jzm-k6f

both return the array as (from `print_r($array)`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company] => Sony
            [city] => Albuquerque
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [company] => GE
            [city] => Boston
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [company] => Skype
            [city] => Chicago
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [company] => Apple
            [city] => Dallas
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [company] => Google
            [city] => Dallas
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [company] => IBM
            [city] => Dallas
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [company] => Dell
            [city] => El Paso
        )

)
```

---

although it is always good to sort in your query

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY city asc, company asc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I see that this is what I was looking for but since my PHP skills aren't very well, I would like to ask you for something which I might didn't understand correctly. If I use the top solution with array=array does this mean that I have to create an array for each Company/City? To do this manually would be difficult since I've got almost 1000 companies in my database. You mentioned a couple of ways - could you please advice the most simple solution for someone with php beginner knowledge.

Comment: Using the first example - `array_multisort()` - you do not need to create an array for each Company/City. You only need to create an array for each column you want to order by (which you said was city and then company). You could easily use either of those examples and just change the `$array` to whatever your array name is. For example if it is in your `foreach ($contry as $g => $v){}` loop, you could change it to - `foreach ($v as $key => $row) {...}` & `array_multisort($city, SORT_ASC, $company, SORT_ASC, $v);`